# How to know which locale is used by my app users most?

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play

Forgive me, I do not know where to ask this question since it was closed in Programmers stack exchange hopefully I will get an answer/comment

My Android app has several languages set in the Res folder as strings.xml in each language's values folder. So if a user's device is using a specific locale that's in my app too, my app will use that locale.
I implemented Google Analytics in my app and it reports in demographics-language that 90% of my users are using "en" locale......and the 4 other locales share the other 10%
However in Android Developer Console, the language tab in statistics, ranks Thailand language the highest, then Greek.... These two Countries rank top two in that order in downloads of my app.

Which one is a true reflection of the locale strings.xml used in my app?

Comment: Do you have Thai and Greek translations? If not, they'll use the default locale, which is probably English. This would explain the 90% locale = en.

Comment: I think the question is to find out what language does the google play dev console reflect. Im not sure but i think it shows the language of the google play market the user used to access your app. My 1st app had only English for the first couple of months but google play showed me all sorts of languages.....